# Ошибка TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
from random import randint

class Die:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides
    
    def roll_die(self):
        print(f'Кубик брошен! \nВыпало: {randint(1, self.sides)}')

my_die = Die(20)
x = my_die.roll_die()
if x < 20:
    my_die.roll_die()
else:
    print('Победа!')
```

При выполнении программы возникает следующая ошибка:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "c:/Users/Computer/Desktop/Учеба/python_work/9_14v2.py", line 12, in 
>   <module>
>   if x < 20:
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
> ```

Как это можно исправить, и в чем я был не прав?

Comment: `roll_die` возвращает None

Comment: Кубик - это, конечно, `dice`, а не `die`, если что )

Comment: @CrazyElf, Кубик - таки `die`)) Слово `dice` является его множественным числом, т.е. набором игральный костей - "кубики" )  Да, в английском редко используется данное слово в единственном числе вне устойчивых выражений(roll a die), но для имени класса олицетворяющего одну игральную кость а не их набор, лучше все же использовать данную форму )

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас по коду ожидается, что функция `roll_die()` возвращает `int`, а фактически она ничего не возвращает (о чем Python вам в ошибке и говорит) - в ней даже нет `return`-а.. Т.е. должно быть:

```
def roll_die(self):
    result = randint(1, self.sides)
    print(f'Кубик брошен! \nВыпало: {result}')
    return result
```